# About the notation of the probability measures

Tags: probability-theory

About the notation of the probability measures

Our textbook uses the following notation for weak convergence of probability
measure:

$\mu_{n}\overset{w}{\rightarrow}\mu$

The relationship for convengence in distribution and weak convergence
of ``distribution'' measures.

$X_{n}\overset{\mathcal{D}}{\rightarrow}X\Leftrightarrow P^{X_{n}}\overset{w}{\rightarrow}P^{X}$.

I wonder whether $P^{X_{n}}$ and $\mu_{n}$ are the same thing, i.e.
$\mu_{n}\overset{w}{\rightarrow}\mu\Leftrightarrow P^{X_{n}}\overset{w}{\rightarrow}P^{X}$

Thank you!

Comment: It should be since $P^{X_n}$ is a measure on the image space of $X_n$.

Comment: So do we have "$\mu_{n}\overset{w}{\rightarrow}\mu\Leftrightarrow P^{X_{n}}\overset{w}{\rightarrow}P^{X}$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The reason $P^{X_{n}}$ is used is because it indicates that these are distributions of  $X_n$.

They're not (necessarily) "the same thing", but you can show easily that the two definitions are equivalent:

(i) A sequence of probability measures $\alpha_n$ is said to converge weakly to a probability measure $\alpha$ if $\alpha_n[I] \rightarrow \alpha [I] $  for all intervals of continuity I

(ii) A sequence of probability measures  $\alpha_n$ with distributions $F_n$ is said to converge weakly to a probability measure $\alpha$ with distribution $F$ if $F_n(y)\rightarrow F(y)$ for all continuity points y

Comment: Thank you. I saw this argument somewhere. So you think we have $\mu_{n}\overset{w}{\rightarrow}\mu\Leftrightarrow P^{X_{n}}\overset{w}{\rightarrow}P^{X}$ ?

Comment: I checked the textbook. They are the same.